# VBA - Changing Copying from a Directory to copying from a server

Tags: vba, excel, csv, directory

Apreciate any help and excuse me if my terminology is incorrect.

This is a basic macro that opens a file from **loacation A** and copies the specified content,
It then pastes the content into the current Workbooks, specified worksheet and cell, that has run this macro.

My question is around the **"FileName.csv"**. This is currently scheduled to be dumped in **Location A "V:\Dir1\SubDir1\"** periodically.

How would I go about Retrieving this file, **"FileName.csv"**, if I started scheduling it to be dumped in **loacation B `"http://172.1.2.3/Dir1/SubDir1/FileName.csv"`** a server of some sort?
I would obviusly just like to edit the existing macro to allow for this change.

```
Sub CopyCSVFile1()

'workbook to copy from
WBToCopy = "FileName.csv"
'workbook path to copy from
WBpthToCopy = "V:\Dir1\SubDir1\"
'workbook to paste to
'WBToPasteTo = "ResourcesV1.xlsm" not needed here as pasting to active workbook
'workbook sheet to paste to
WBSheetToPasteTo = "Raw1"
''workbook path to paste to
'WBPthToPasteTo = "N:\Engineering\Network Performance\Capacity\SG_GG\SGSN Resources\" ' not needed here as pasting to active workbook
'range to select to copy
RangeToSelectToCopy = "A3:B149"
'cell to paste to
CellToPasteTo = "A3" ' need to work this out before assignment

Dim Merged As Object
Dim Data As Object
Set Data = ActiveWorkbook

'debug.print "ActiveWorkbook.Path = " & ActiveWorkbook.Path
Debug.Print "ActiveWorkbook.Path = " & Data.Path

Sheets(WBSheetToPasteTo).Select ' this is the sheet where you want to paste to
Workbooks.Open Filename:=WBpthToCopy & WBToCopy, local:=True

Set Merged = ActiveWorkbook ' this assigns the current active workbook to merged whish is the one I want to copy from

Range(RangeToSelectToCopy).Select ' this value just for this example should be A4 normally
Selection.Copy

Data.Activate ' this activates the Data workbook which happens to be the workbook where this macro resides

Range(CellToPasteTo).Select ' select where I want to past my data

ActiveSheet.Paste ' paste the data
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Merged.Close 'SaveChanges = False

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
Sub CopyCSVFile1()

    Dim wb As WorkBook, WBToCopy As String, WBpthToCopy As String

    'workbook to copy from
    WBToCopy = "test.csv"

    'workbook path to copy from
    WBpthToCopy = "http://127.0.0.1/testpages/"

    'open the source workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(WBpthToCopy & WBToCopy)

    '...
    'do something with wb...
    '...

    wb.Close False

End Sub
```

Comment: tks  Tim I will give that a go.